# How do you translate the pluperfect subjunctive in English?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, subjunctives

- "*I may have carried the box but at the time I had back pains*"

I'm trying to translate the *pluperfect subjunctive* from Latin into English using the verb '**to carry**' but I'm not sure if this makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You want "would" here.

> I would have carried the box, but at the time, I had back pains.

You could also use "might." But the tense is wrong for "may."

Comment: And in any case "may had" is never grammatical as a verb form, whatever the tense. Modals such as "may" are followed by the base form, not an inflected form such as the past.